# Status com jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Possuo o html com as seguintes divs:

```
<div class="tag" id="div-statusActive" data-status="statusActive">
    <div class="tag__title tag__title--spaced">
        <span data-bind="widgetLocaleText: 'statusActive'"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tag" id="div-statusPendingPayment" data-status="statusPendingPayment">
    <div class="tag__title tag__title--spaced">
        <span data-bind="widgetLocaleText: 'statusPendingPayment'"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="tag__action">
        <span class="icon-alert-circle"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tag" id="div-statusCancellationPending" data-status="statusCancel_requested">
    <div class="tag__title tag__title--spaced">
        <span data-bind="widgetLocaleText: 'statusCancellationPending'"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tag" id="div-statusSignatureCanceled" data-status="statusCanceled">
    <div class="tag__title tag__title--spaced">
        <span data-bind="widgetLocaleText: 'statusSignatureCanceled'"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

o jquery busca o resultado em uma api e mostra qual o status da conta, porém não está funcionando.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
$('div[data-status="' + state + '"]').show()
</script>
```

qual o motivo?

Comment: Verifique se no retorno está vindo a string esperada com `console.log(state)`.

Comment: Seu html parece estar incompleto, e você não de usar scripts dentro de tag scripts que importam um script externo. Sugiro que dê uma olhada em [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e após isso edite sua pergunta para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Outra coisa, seu script está errado. Use uma tag script para carregar o jQuery e outra com o código, e não tudo no mesmo script.

Comment: o retorno do console.log é PROCESSING.

Comment: os scripts estão em um arquivo diferente do html, quando o status é ativo o retorno é correto, utilizando $('div[data-status=statusActive]').show()

Comment: Observe o comentário do Vinicius e o último meu. Vc está carregando o jQuery numa tag script e inserindo código na mesma tag. Vc tem que usar duas tags script, uma para carregar o jQuery e outra com o código.

Comment: Como já disseram acima vc tem que fechar a tag, abrir e fechar novamente. Assim: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script> <script>
$('div[data-status="' + state + '"]').show()
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.tag').hide(); // esconde todos os status

var status = "SignatureCanceled" ; // adicione aqui o status desejado

$('#div-status'+status).show(); //complete o id do div desejado com sua variável para exibir
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tag" id="div-statusActive" data-status="statusActive">
    <div class="tag__title tag__title--spaced">
        <span data-bind="widgetLocaleText: 'statusActive'">statusActive</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tag" id="div-statusPendingPayment" data-status="statusPendingPayment">
    <div class="tag__title tag__title--spaced">
        <span data-bind="widgetLocaleText: 'statusPendingPayment'">statusPendingPayment</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tag__action">
        <span class="icon-alert-circle"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tag" id="div-statusCancellationPending" data-status="statusCancel_requested">
    <div class="tag__title tag__title--spaced">
        <span data-bind="widgetLocaleText: 'statusCancellationPending'">statusCancellationPending</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tag" id="div-statusSignatureCanceled" data-status="statusCanceled">
    <div class="tag__title tag__title--spaced">
        <span data-bind="widgetLocaleText: 'statusSignatureCanceled'">statusSignatureCanceled</span>
    </div>
</div>
```